# mediaWiki categories vs. subpages for organizing content

Tags: mediawiki, categorization

I want to create a wiki where the content can and therefore probably should be clearly separated by categories, for reasons of search-ability and clarity.

Let's take as a random example a wiki where every site describes the situation of a movie director at a given point in time. I would have pages with an organization logic as follows: `Year > Month > director's situation`, but also `Year > Month > Day > director's situation` and `Year > director's situation`.

1976 > September > Woody Allen: Mr. Allen was shooting Annie Hall.

1977 > Woody Allen: Mr. Allen turned x that year.

1979 > February > Woody Allen: Mr. Allen was cutting Manhattan.

Ok it's a dumb example, but it gets the point across. So now for every time frame there are Woody Allen pages with different content.
I want to achieve good search-ability, given that the titles in my real application won't be as obvious as names, and unique identification of the different pages. My question is what is the best strategy to achieve this in mediaWiki given the clear categorization of content?

1. Creating a hierarchy of categories (eg. Year > Month > Day:
   directors) and a matching hierarchy of subpages (Year/Month/Day/directors).
2. Creating a hierarchy of categories and
   then just have a page titles like "Director, Year, Month Day"
3. Just organizing everything with subpages.
4. ....

I would opt for #1. The hierarchy of categories allows for clean searching with `+incategory:"Category Name"` and the hierarchy of subpages allows for prettier page titles (especially if categories have long names). Is there any pitfall with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, [Semantic Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_MediaWiki) would offer you a lot of options for sorting, indexing, and searching for pages by whatever parameters or metadata you want without the need of nested categories or specialized titles. This is my recommended solution for nearly all questions of wiki organization.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I already was eying Semantic MediaWiki for data-content tagging etc, but will now look into its page content organization features in more detail. It will not solve the problem of unique urls though... I guess I was just wondering why the wikimedia projects avoid using subpages.

Comment: The main reason Wikimedia projects don't use subpages in the mainspace is because page titles are purely syntactic, so if you had a page called `Foo/Bar` and enabled subpages, the wiki would convert it to a subpage of `Foo` (which probably doesn't exist). So in order to avoid such problems, subpages are disabled by default. If you can be confident that it won't screw up your article titles (or you're willing to go through and rename all affected pages) then subpages aren't a problem.

Comment: If not, you can still create 'fake subpages' with the subpage naming convention (`page/subpage`) for organizational purposes. If you need to link to such fake subpages in an automated fashion (such as in templates), then you can just use a `{{#titleparts:}}` function where you'd usually rely on the `{{SUBPAGENAME}}` series of magic words.